# add filter in custom admin grid before load data in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Here i have to add filter in charity and fee column,if charity is filled then display in grid otherwise that data  should not show in grid.

But here all record's are displayed.
Thank you..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit `Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\Grid\Collection` file and add below function in it.

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
    $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.status = 1');
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

Comment: But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your ui component add the following code

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
        </filters>

 <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: any issues let me know

Comment: Thanks, But its add only new column.

Comment: add this line for each column <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>